# Preserving dimensions with variable NumPy slice

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have a 3d NumPy array from which I would like to take many slices. These slices will have a length of one or more in the first and second dimensions, whereas the third will be returned in its entirety. The slice should always be 3d.

My attempt at this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((1000, 10, 100))
row_sets = ([19, 20], [21])
col_sets = ([6], [7, 8])

for rows in row_sets:
    for cols in col_sets:
        b = a[[rows], [cols]]
        print(rows, cols, b.shape)
```

The results:

```
[19, 20] [6] (1, 2, 100)
[19, 20] [7, 8] (1, 2, 100)
[21] [6] (1, 1, 100)
[21] [7, 8] (1, 2, 100)
```

If I remove the nested brackets from the slice:

```
b = a[rows, cols]
```

I have what appears to be the same issue in the second dimension, and dimensionality is not preserved:

```
[19, 20] [6] (2, 100)
[19, 20] [7, 8] (2, 100)
[21] [6] (1, 100)
[21] [7, 8] (2, 100)
```

The result I am looking for would be like this:

```
[19, 20] [6] (2, 1, 100)
[19, 20] [7, 8] (2, 2, 100)
[21] [6] (1, 1, 100)
[21] [7, 8] (1, 2, 100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are triggering *[advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing)* by using list of integers as the index, which reduces the dimensions of the result array, if you want to slice the array still, you can use [np.ix_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) to reconstruct the slice index from list of ints:

```
for rows in row_sets:
    for cols in col_sets:
        b = a[np.ix_(rows, cols)]
        print(rows, cols, b.shape)

#[19, 20] [6] (2, 1, 100)
#[19, 20] [7, 8] (2, 2, 100)
#[21] [6] (1, 1, 100)
#[21] [7, 8] (1, 2, 100)
```